# Do apps included in the gApps zip get updated via Google Play?

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, google-apps

While using alternative ROMs like CyanogenMod 9(as i currently am), one flashes an additional zip file called gApps which contains apps provided by Google.

As Google releases newer versions of applications, will the newer versions be updated via Google Play or do I need to manually flash a newer version of the gapps.zip?

I'm asking because an update to the Google Play market app was recently released (which includes the ability to remove apps from the ALL MY APPS section) but I still haven't seen my market app updating itself.

Comment: I am on unofficial CM10 on LGP500. The Google's apps were installed through gapps.zip and are getting updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Gapps *will* be updatable via Play Store. You can set them to update automatically if you will (personally, I don't. I always try to find a free wifi hotspot to do updates ;)

More specific answer: The Play Store app updates itself silently in the background; you will never be asked for an update.

Longer answer: Gapps must be installed separately because the apps in the Gapps set are *not* open-source. It was a compromise reached between Google and ROM devs. In essence, ROM devs are free to create their own version of ROM as long as they exclude Gapps, but Google then went further to provide an installable Gapps.

That is why Gapps' updatezip are rarely updated; after all, Gapps still have the ability to be upgraded via Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

Gapps are not included in CyanogenMod by default. You have to flash them separately through recovery. These apps will will show update notifications automatically when connected to the internet. In the case of the play store app you will not see it updating in the foreground. It downloads and updates without any notification. In case it hasn't updated you can search in google for the latest apk and install it.

Comment: Voted -1, because whether Gapps update automatically or not *totally* depends on whether you allow them to update automatically ... or not.